# Generic class implementing Iterable

Tags: java, iterable

I want to have a generic class that implements Iterable (let's call it ImplIterable) of type T that implements an Iterable interface over some class (that isn't of the generic class type); for example:

```
public class ImplIterable <T> implements Iterable<A> {
   private A[] tab;

   public Iterator<A> iterator() {
      return new ImplIterator();
   }

   // doesn't work - but compiles correctly.
   private class ImplIterator implements Iterator<A> {
      public boolean hasNext() { return true; }

      public A next() { return null; }

      public void remove() {}
   }
}
```

Where A is some class. Now, this code won't compile:

```
ImplIterable iable = new ImplIterable();
for (A a : iable) {
   a.aStuff();
}
```

But this will:

```
Iterable<A> = new ImplIterable();
for (A a : iable) {
   a.aStuff();
}
```

I don't understand why the latter doesn't compile and why can't I iterate over ImplIterable if it properly implements iterable. Am I doing something wrong/is there some workaround for this type of problems?

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: `incompatible types
found   : java.lang.Object
required: java.lang.String`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a generic class without a generic parameter, all generics in that class are disabled.

Since `ImplIterable` is generic, and you're using it as a non-generic class, the generic parameters inside of it vanish, and it becomes an `Iterable` (non-generic) of `Object`s.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know generics worked this way. ImplIterable<Void> works, as does any type. So the former case works because the generic type in Iterable<A> isn't erased - which makes sense in a way.

Comment: You're welcome.  This happens for compatibility reasons.  You should accept this answer by clicking the hollow check.